# Работа с коллекциями

Tags: javascript, ооп, коллекции

дали задание, где нужно используя коллекции создать 2 библиотеки с определенным кол-вом книг и проводить операции над ними. Там каждая книга должна иметь поля типа: автор, название книги, кол-во страниц. Раньше я делал это через конструктор, в котором через this создавал нужные атрибуты.

Читал документацию на мозила мдн, понял, что нужно работать с set, но не нашел ни одного примера, который подходил бы моему. Подскажите пример, как мне реализовать это все.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что тебе нужен `set`? кстати, что это?

Comment: @Grundy сохранение любых значений типа

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что он тебе нужен? Что конкретно раньше ты делал через конструктор?

Comment: _понял, что нужно работать с set_ -  ты ошибся - не нужно :)

Comment: @Grundy
`class Persona {
    constructor(first, last, day, month, year) {
        this.name = {
            first,
            last
        };
        this.Birthday = {
            day,
            month,
            year
        };
    }`

Comment: И почему ты думаешь, что вместо класса `Book` тебе вдруг надо использовать `Set`?

Comment: @Grundy тема практичной работы коллекции, set.
Просто подскажите как мне подобное реализовать.
Там просто должно быть создано 2 библиотеки с неким кол-вом книг и проводить над ними операции, типа получить все книги с двух коллекций по дате и тд

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85438/discussion-between-grundy-and-apper).